# htaccess invisibly redirect everything into a directory

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect all requests into a subdirectory?

I've tried this, and lots of other things:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webroot/(.*)
RewriteRule $ webroot/$1 [NC,L]
```

What I want is to protect the contents of the otherwise web-accessible directory the requests would ordinarily go to, and have them mapped onto the webroot directory.

Comment: You description is confusing. Please provide an example of original URL and how you want to be rewritten (from => to). P.S. Your current rule makes no sense.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to seeing as it's not working ;)

There are no specifics - I want everything to be redirected so test.example.com would look for an index.php under /webroot instead of document root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule below will rewrite (internal redirect) **EVERYTHING** into `/webroot/` subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webroot/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 [L]
```